# Zend framework's getRequest()->getQuery() won't bring query string on localhost

Tags: zend-framework, request, query-string

I have the following code, which works fine on live site, but not on localhost.

```
$status = $this->getRequest()->getQuery('status');
```

I have a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:888//questions/ask?status=10
```

I printed the value of status, which is always nil. I am new to Zend framework and could not find a solution to this on net, looks strange to me. Any thoughts?
Thanks.

**[FIXED]**

I had wrong RewriteRule that caused the problem. There was an unwanted '?' after `index.php`  in RewriteRule line. It was my mistake I added this, because other frameworks like CodeIgniter user '?' in RewriteRules. The corrected RewriteRule line is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I wonder if I can choose this as accepted answer.. :-)

Comment: you get to the action controller? .htaccess is working? just the parameter is null?

Comment: ZF2 it works `$post = $this->getRequest();
    $productid = mysql_real_escape_string($post->getQuery('productid'));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually use this

```
$status = $this->getRequest()->getParam('status');

// or
$status = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

I assume that you have a Questions Controller Ask Action.
Here is the [documentation about Zend's request](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.request.html)

Comment: Elzo, I tried that, I always get module, controller, action, etc, but not query strings. This works as it should be on live, only localhost has problems. Am I missing any of framework's config?

Comment: have any strange routing in place? or other settings that are ENVIRONMENT dependent?

Comment: var_dump the request object. if the status variable is in the url it should appear there as well.

Comment: My request object never had 'status'. The only problem I had was wrong RewriteRule, I update my question. Thanks Elzo.

Comment: using zend 3, getting error after using your solution: Call to undefined method Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request::getParams()

Comment: this response was valid for ZF1 @Kamlesh

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for the solution to ZF2 - look at this post, helped me out dramatically.  It even includes the reference to a phenomenal plugin to make this easier (as the very least, in understanding the routes/requests/params, etc...)

[Getting $_GET parameters from route in Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820889/getting-get-parameters-from-route-in-zend-framework-2)

Also, in this post SO post

[How to access route, post, get etc. parameters in Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077126/how-to-access-route-post-get-etc-parameters-in-zend-framework-2)

In short, tho -

```
    $this->getRequest()->getRequest('name', 'default');
    $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('name', 'default');
```