# How to access route, post, get etc. parameters in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, file-upload, zend-route, zend-framework2

How can I get various parameters related to the page request in zf2? Like post/get parameters, the route being accessed, headers sent and files uploaded.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

The easiest way to do that would be to use the [Params plugin](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Controller/Plugin/Params.php), introduced in beta5. It has utility methods to make it easy to access different types of parameters. As always, reading [the tests](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/test/Controller/Plugin/ParamsTest.php) can prove valuable to understand how something is supposed to be used.

### Get a single value

To get the value of a named parameter in a controller, you will need to select the appropriate method for the type of parameter you are looking for and pass in the name.

#### Examples:

```
$this->params()->fromPost('paramname');   // From POST
$this->params()->fromQuery('paramname');  // From GET
$this->params()->fromRoute('paramname');  // From RouteMatch
$this->params()->fromHeader('paramname'); // From header
$this->params()->fromFiles('paramname');  // From file being uploaded
```

### Default values

All of these methods also support default values that will be returned if no parameter with the given name is found.

#### Example:

```
$orderBy = $this->params()->fromQuery('orderby', 'name');
```

When visiting http://example.com/?orderby=birthdate,
*$orderBy* will have the value ***birthdate***.
When visiting http://example.com/,
*$orderBy* will have the *default* value ***name***.

### Get all parameters

To get all parameters of one type, just don't pass in anything and the Params plugin will return an array of values with their names as keys.

#### Example:

```
$allGetValues = $this->params()->fromQuery(); // empty method call
```

When visiting http://example.com/?orderby=birthdate&filter=hasphone *$allGetValues* will be an array like

```
array(
    'orderby' => 'birthdate',
    'filter'  => 'hasphone',
);
```

### Not using Params plugin

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Controller/Plugin/Params.php) for the Params plugin, you will see that it's just a thin wrapper around other controllers to allow for more consistent parameter retrieval. If you for some reason want/need to access them directly, you can see in the source code how it's done.

#### Example:

```
$this->getRequest()->getRequest('name', 'default');
$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('name', 'default');
```

**NOTE:** You could have used the superglobals $_GET, $_POST etc., but that is discouraged.

Comment: Calling params plugin directly is also possible, it is a shortcut to fromRoute(): `$this->params('key', 'default')`

Comment: @Robin that is true. Note that you cannot use it to fetch all route parameters, because calling it with no parameters will return the Params plug in and not route stuff.

Comment: +1 for the unit tests comment+link. Few think to check out the unit tests for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

The easisest way to get a posted json string, for example, is to read the contents of 'php://input' and then decode it. For example i had a simple Zend route:

```
'save-json' => array(
'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/save-json/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'CDB\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'save-json',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

and i wanted to post data to it using Angular's $http.post. The post was fine but the retrive method in Zend

```
$this->params()->fromPost('paramname');
```

didn't get anything in this case. So my solution was, after trying all kinds of methods like $_POST and the other methods stated above, to read from 'php://':

```
$content = file_get_contents('php://input');
print_r(json_decode($content));
```

I got my json array in the end. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: If you need the raw POST body use the getContent() of the request object. From a controller, you could do: `$content = $this->getRequest()->getContent()`

Comment: On ZF2 how can we retrieve a URL parameter in the form of `?name=mike` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once 'lib/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
$loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister_zf' => true));

$loader->registerNamespace('Http\PhpEnvironment', 'lib/Zend/Http'); 

// Register with spl_autoload:
$loader->register();

$a = new Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request();
print_r($a->getQuery()->get()); exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

If You have no access to plugin for instance outside of  controller You can get params from servicelocator like this

```
//from POST
$foo = $this->serviceLocator->get('request')->getPost('foo'); 
//from GET
$foo = $this->serviceLocator->get('request')->getQuery()->foo;
//from route
$foo = $this->serviceLocator->get('application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above methods will work fine if your content-type is "application/-www-form-urlencoded".
But if your content-type is "application/json" then you will have to do the following:

$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($params);

Reason : See #7 in https://www.toptal.com/php/10-most-common-mistakes-php-programmers-make