# Zend Framework 2 can´t receive HTTP Post - "get was unable to fetch or create an instance for fromPost"

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, http-post, zend-autoloader

I´m new in ZF2 and I have a problem with reveiving the post/get Parameters in my Controller.
Following Exception appears:

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException

Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for fromPost
```

My index.phtml

...

```
<form id="formActionCl" action="/public/checklistCore/delete" method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="butto_doAction<?php echo $index;?>" hidden="true" value="<?php echo $this->translate('button_confirm_action', 'checklist');?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="checklist" value="<?php echo $index;?>">
</form>
```

...

And the Controller:

```
    use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPluginManager,
```

...

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    $cl_id = $this->fromPost('checklist');
    echo $cl_id;
    //$cl_id = $_GET['checklist'];
    $checklist = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('ChecklistCore\Entity\Checklist')->find($cl_id);
    $checklist->status = 'inactiv';

    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($checklist);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

    return $this->redirect()->toUrl('index');
}
```

I think I have forgott something in the module.config, but I can´t find anything, how to declare the serviceManager right ([module.config.php](http://pastebin.com/uinHKRup))

Comment: See this answer on how to get post and other data in zend framework 2: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12077127/923847

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes are needed. First, as Tim wrote, it should be

```
$cl_id = $this->params()->fromPost('checklist');
```

Second, form items are passed to the controller by name, not id. So in addition to the id field on the element, you need a name field, as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" id="checklist" name="checklist" value="<?php echo $index;?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean:

```
$cl_id = $this->params()->fromPost('checklist');
```

assuming you're trying to grab a POST variable.

Comment: Yeah thanks! But I have still a problem - I can´t get the value of the hidden field (see the phtml form code) - Is there something wrong with the form? btw - the http post includes no data in firebug..