# Pass parameters by URL in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm getting into trouble with passing paramters by URL in Zend Framework.

For example, I have a Controller like this:

```
class MyController extends AbstractActionController {
    public function indexAction() { ... }
    public function updateAction($id) { ... }
}
```

I want to access the update page by a URL like this: http://example.com/mycontroller/update/1

So how to pass the value 1 to the controller?

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

BTW, I have changed the default router from

```
'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]'
```

to

```
'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action[/:id]]]',
```

but it still doesn't work. And here's the error message below.

`Warning: Missing argument 1 for Module\Controller\MyController::updateAction() call in ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem!

You should change the function as following:

```
public function updateAction()
{
    $paramName = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('id');

    // Do something with $paramName

    return array();
}
```

There're more methods to get parameters in Zend Framework2:
[How to access route, post, get etc. parameters in Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077126/how-to-access-route-post-get-etc-parameters-in-zend-framework-2)

Comment: Yes, and it seems to be simpler.