# Fetching query string parameter in PHP

Tags: php, get, query-string, fetch

I have a little problem regarding fetching the query string in php...

The initial URL that I used to have was like following:

```
www.sitename.com/?id=someid
```

Fetching was done with the following method:

```
if(!empty(htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"])) && empty($me))
    {
        $_SESSION['FriendID'] = $userId;

        return $this->redirect()->toUrl("/user/emailsignup");
    }
```

Now I had to add a name to the URL with slashes like this:

```
www.sitename.com/SomeName/?id=someid
```

With this URL I'm getting an error...

How can I fetch the Id now with the backslashes added to the query string, so that the If statement does its job properly??

Thanks heaps!!

Comment: can you post the error message you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting a custom error from the application... it says "Oops, that page isn't available

For some reason, the page you were looking for isn't here. Try again later"

Comment: You ain't doing anything wrong to access it. Using `$_GET['id']` is just fine for this.

Comment: it's laravel? you can try configuration display error

Comment: No this is Zend framework @Naumov

Comment: @Akshay apparently not... The error is there, not sure why tho ... :/

Comment: Have you checked the HTTP status code?

Comment: Have you created a new route for that URL? I don't think it's an issue with the query string parameter. It sounds like you aren't even getting to that page. `$_GET["id"]` should still work if you are.

Comment: @Don'tPanic no how can I do that? Can u reply as an answer and post how to do that, I think that might be the case here...

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not that familiar with Zend Framework. I can only point you to what looks like it should be the appropriate documentation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html

Comment: If you are using a framework make sure you add the framework tag to your question. The answer for getting the query param in for example Zend Framework or Zend Framework 2 is very different from getting such thing in just php.

Comment: For zend framework you find your will answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3733681/1697459) and for zend framework 2 you will find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12077127/1697459)