# First param of the Query String not being sent on AJAX call as GET parameter, why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using this code to sent an AJAX call within a Select2 element:

```
var condition_type = 'something'; // this is dynamic but I turned on a string for demonstration
var field_value = 'something_1'; // this is dynamic but I turned on a string for demonstration

$('#condition_value_1').select2({
  placeholder: 'Start typing ...',
  allowClear: true,
  tags: true,
  ajax: {
    url: '/search',
    dataType: 'json',
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    delay: 250,
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        keyword: params.term,
        condition: condition_type,
        field: field_value
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data) {
      return {
        results: data.items
      };
    }
  }
});
```

The code above works and is sending an AJAX request with the following structure:

```
/search?keyword=some&condition=something&field=something_1
```

I should be getting three `GET` parameters but instead I am getting only the last two and I am not sure why this behavior. Take a look to the debug window from phpStorm:

[image]

Notice how `condition` and `field` are part of the `REQUEST` and are being passed as `GET` parameters but where is the first one `keyword`? Shouldn't be part of the `REQUEST` as well? I am missing something here on the configuration either PHP or Select2?

Comment: keyword: params.term - where do you call that function and pass the 'params' variable, the other 2 condition and field are accessed through the variables at the top, params.term is undefinded

Comment: @baskin not sure what are you talking about, can you be more clear?

Comment: data: function(params) , where are you passing params in?

Comment: @baskin from [docs](https://select2.github.io/options.html#i-want-to-add-more-query-parameters-to-the-request-where-can-th)

Comment: So if you are seeing it in the querystring, than the issue is not with the plugin, but the serverside.

Comment: weird indeed, perhaps some Rewrite rule getting in the middle, like this one was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733454/zend-frameworks-getrequest-getquery-wont-bring-query-string-on-localhost

Comment: @arhak you're right I've tried the solution in that post and it works.